# PHP foreach will only work once within my html tables

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

Full code:

```
<table id="table-1">
<thead>
  <th>Group Member</th>
  <th>Member's Balance</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($members as $mem) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $mem['nick_name']; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
  </table>
<form action="./?action=pay_member" method="post" id="pay_org_member_form" >
  <table id="table-1">
<thead>
    <th>Group member</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Description</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
       <select name="member_ID">
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $member['member_ID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $member['nick_name']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td>$<input type="input" name="amount" /></td>
    <td><input type="input" name="description" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem I'm having now is the original table stopped pulling the $member variable. Only the new one works. It seems like I can only use this once. Anyway to get around this?

`$members` is declared like so:

```
Ok, $members is declared like so:

$members = get_other_members_by_org($org_ID, $member_ID);
```

and

```
function get_other_members_by_org($org_ID, $member_ID) {
global $db;
$query = "SELECT members.member_ID, nick_name, email_address 
          FROM 
            (members INNER JOIN orgs_to_members ON orgs_to_members.member_ID = members.member_ID)
          WHERE org_ID = '$org_ID' AND members.member_ID != '$member_ID'";
$members = $db->query($query);
return $members;
```

Comment: It definitely should work. What you have in between? Make sure you do not rewrite the variable. Post the full code, not the a gist please.

Comment: Bits you gave look correct. Is there anything that has anything at all to do with `$members` in between?

Comment: full code is posted now. thanks.

Comment: When I added the top table, the bottom table stopped pulling the option value.

Comment: @Progger That's not what we meant... We meant you show us how `$members` gets declared. That full code.

Comment: do you have error_reporting enabled?

Comment: sorry about the mess - will repost above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first foreach consumes the query. Requery, or put the results into an array.

Comment: Sorry I am a little new to PHP. Can you please explain further? I don't really understand.

Comment: You can only drink all the water from a cup once. Refill the cup.